# Client side <serviceCertificate> and <identity> elements

Tags: wcf

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731782.aspx) for `<serviceCertificate>`says this

> This configuration element specifies the settings used by 
>   the client
>   to validate the certificate presented by the service using SSL
>   authentication.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731721(v=vs.110).aspx) for `<identity>` says this

> In the handshake process between the client and service, the Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) infrastructure will ensure that the
>   identity of the expected service matches the values of this element,
>   and thus can be authenticated.

As I understand, both these elements are used to authenticate service to the client.

**Question:** Could someone please elaborate and let me know the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are quite different.

- As its name implies, the `<identity>` element is used by the client to identify a service, answering the question **"Who are you?"** It contains many child elements that can be used for this purpose - as there are many ways of identifying a service: certificate, SPN, UPN, etc.
- `<serviceCertificate>` specifies an actual X.509 certificate used to authenticate a client or service, helping to answer the question **"How can I be sure you are who you say you are?"**